# Changing value of $_SESSION variable using submit button

Tags: php, session

I am trying to make code changing news pages and I am having difficulties.
`$_SESSION['page']` doesn't change value and always stays as `1`.
Thank you.

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if (!isset($_POST['set_page'])) {
      $_SESSION['page'] = 1;
   }
   else {
      eval("return '".$_POST['change_page']."';");
   }
   echo "Page ".$_SESSION['page'];
   echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="change_page" value="$_SESSION["page"]++"/>';
   echo '<input type="submit" name="set_page" value="Next Page"></form></p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement here is wrong ++ operator will work like that change that line like this

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="change_page" value="'.$_SESSION["page"]++.'"/>';
```

and your single quotes, When you embed some variable inside string use double quotes or use concatenation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I wasn't able to figure it out by myself.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for up, but when I'll get some more reputation I certainly will.

Comment: @Pavel Thanks, people simply give -1s for no reason.Tommorow I will give you a up. Today voting limit reached.

Comment: Sometimes people give +1 for no reason too.